# Cannot create any instance

Tags: cloud, apache-cloudstack

I'm new to Cloud services, and i'm trying to install Apache Cloudstack. I followed all the instructions in http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/4.8/ 
I completed the guide, but when i try to create a new instance, the list of templates and ISOS its empty. Since i know that exists templates i have no clue with whats happening.

I have looked for solutions and some point to this https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CLOUDSTACK/SSVM%2C+templates%2C+Secondary+storage+troubleshooting
but i can't find /usr/local/cloud/systemvm/ssvm-check.sh anywhere

Answer (score 0):

you have to login to SSVM using link local ip. Then you will see that script.